# Android back key event - while displaying soft keyboard

Tags: android, back-button, android-softkeyboard

I'm trying to catch the back key event using `boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)` while showing the soft keyboard. But it is not working...

Comment: Here the way, I catched the back key event. http://stackoverflow.com/a/40340213/3957916

Answer (score 1):

override this method of Edittext:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        //put your logic here
        }
    return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event);
}
```

you will get event on backpress inside if.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
//your code
return true;
}
```

Warning: You are informing Android system that you already handled the back key press and it will not perform as intended inside the Application (will not exit).

Comment: onKeyDown() isn't called when the SoftKeyboard isn't hidden.

Comment: From the Document, I think it is possible :Key presses in software keyboards will generally NOT trigger this listener, *although some may elect to do so in some situations*