# how to make android device back button to dismiss activity instead of just dismiss keyboard?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, onbackpressed

I have an activity with search bar. On start, keyboard shows up.

If I hit back button, it dismisses the keyboard. I need to hit back button 3 times to dismiss activity. The first hit dismisses keyboard, second hit loses focus from search bar.

How to dismiss activity using back button?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android key event for back key when soft keyboard is shown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19637272/android-key-event-for-back-key-when-soft-keyboard-is-shown)

Comment: remove super from onBackpressed and use finish()

Answer (score 0):

You can catch back event and add your own destination activity as follows

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK ) {
        // finish current activity  ( finish(); )
        // add your new intent here
        // Example:
        // startActivity(new Intent(<your_context>, <destination_activity>));
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: This code only gets executed on 3rd hit of device back key. The first hit dismissed keyboard, second hit loses focus from search bar.

Comment: If you want to disable default behavior of `onKeyDown`, return `true` instead of `super`